# Is there a generic way to replace referential constraints with triggers?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Porting application from MSSQL+Oracle to Sybase, and there's an issue with 'on delete cascade' - Sybase doesn't have the option.

Sybase has a link with a trigger to implement cascading delete: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug815.htm
but there is a problem with that solution when put into context of using it as 'on delete cascade'.

The problem, is triggers get executed after any referential constraints are checked.
The issue is illustrated here:

```
--drop table A
--drop table B
create table A (c int primary key)
create table B (c int primary key)

alter table A
add constraint Ac FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES B(c)

create trigger delBA on B for delete 
as delete A from A, deleted where A.c = deleted.c

insert into B values (1)
insert into A values (1)

delete B where c = 1
```

The 'delete' statement will fail, because of 'Ac' constraint.  Had the trigger fired before the check for referential constraints (instead of after), it would have removed the value '1' from table 'A' and there would not be a problem.

For this reason, I'm thinking to implement the referential constraint by using a trigger.  So I have to create an Insert and Update trigger, I believe.  Is there some template that I can use?

I want to make sure I'm not overlooking anything, at first look at the issue, I missed that update trigger should be written so that it can validate that after update the constraint is still valid.  - That is the reason I'm looking for a template, so I won't miss anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are often sources of trouble. A common approach would be to set up your data access layer that will create a transaction, delete the 'children' (cascade part) then delete the parent.